# How to Dual Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. Option "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows 7 does not show up"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

sorry to open a new thread with the same and question again and again, but people wouldn't open it again and again, if Ubuntu would work out of the box like the tutorials explain it to work.

I have Windows 7 and I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7.

1. I freed up some space on my partition to make place for an Ubuntu installation.

   [image: Windows Volume Manager]
2. Next I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14.04 to an USB stick and booted from USB to start the installation and here does the problem start. I get this image:

   [image: Ubuntu installation]

   Where the option to "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows 7" is missing.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I make this message appear. I don't want to proceed necessarily just without this option, because I did this on my Desktop Computer yesterday and got the following problems:

1. I would not get a Boot Menu, because Windows 7 would just boot out of the box
2. After a little bit reconfiguration I lost my Windows 7 partition with all its data

Therefore I want to activate the option: "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows 7". How do I get this?

**Update**: I was told in #ubuntu IRC to delete the unpartitioned space and to try to just reboot, because Ubuntu allegedly has an issue, if the HDD has more than 4 partitions.

When I live boot to view the accessible partitions I get this image:

[image]

Now I wonder what I can do next? I might even consider proceeding with using the option "Other Options" but I am afraid I will lose my other partition.

Comment: I'd say that it'll be a lot easier to just use the “something else” option, than try to resolve the issue, that disables the “alongside” option. The two issues you describe at the end can appear just as well with the “alongside” option.

Comment: Thanks David, I updated my issue and will probably proceed with your suggestion, by exploring my choices I have through "something else". Still if you have an idea on how to activate the "alongside" option I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Do you have sda3 & sda4 as empty partitions or available? Better to use parted to list partitions.  You must have one available primary partition to install alongside. And Windows must not be hibernated nor needing chkdsk so Linux can see the Windows partition. Does Windows need chkdsk or is it hibernated?